# Windows wont recognise android device

Tags: usb, windows, usb-drivers

I wanted to start afresh completely wipe my Moto x (xt1052) and install "liquidsmooth" rom.

everyone was going well, i went into recovery, wiped the device, and as i tried to push the zip over i was met with the error message "device not found"

I went over to device manager and for some reason windows is recognizing my phone as xt1060 and not xt1052. i believe this is why its probably not being recognised in adb.

I have no idea to fix, my phone is being recognised as another phone so it cant even install right driver...

Comment: Have you tried using the drivers from [Motorola Device Manager?](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481) Installing that should replace the driver you have now.

Comment: yes i have, i even tried installing it manually from the drivers folder.

Answer (score 0):

install drivers for your phone
look for drivers at

- your phone manufacturer's website
  or
- look at your chipset manufacturer's website.

if Driver didn't install properly turn off Driver signature enforcement on windows from boot options

[Link for how to disabled Driver signature enforcement](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/)

and install drivers
reboot your PC 
plug in your phone

hope that helped
cheers !!!